# How to parse a Twitch API response in Python

Tags: python, arrays, object

I have the following API call...

```
response = requests.get(address, headers=headers, params=params)
```

I get a successful return and can see the data when I..

`print(response.text)`

The documentation says...

> The API returns an array of stream objects, along with a cursor for
>   pagination.

It gives an example response.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "28623425344",
      "user_id": "150573462",
      "game_id": "488191",
      "community_ids": [
        "848d95be-90b3-44a5-b143-6e373754c382",
        "8deb7b0f-d5a3-4f9d-942d-2331d8f4fe3d",
        "ff1e77af-551d-4993-945c-f8ceaa2a2829"
      ],
      "type": "live",
      "title": "CHILL // PSYCHEDELIA :: ambience \u0026 tones  [ !visuals ]",
      "viewer_count": 9001,
      "started_at": "2018-05-08T18:47:34Z",
      "language": "en",
      "thumbnail_url": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_amorelandra-{width}x{height}.jpg"
    }
    ...
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "cursor": "eyJiIjpudWxsLCJhIjp7Ik9mZnNldCI6MX19"
  }
}
```

I don't know how to access for example, `user_id` from the `response` variable.

I'm new to Python.

I tried

`print(response.data[0].user_id)` but I get

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Comment: `response.json()[0]['user_id']`

Comment: I recieved `KeyError: 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the response string into a Python dictionary with the json library. Try this:

```
from json import loads
loads(response.text)['data'][0]['user_id']
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great thanks.  I didn't know it was a json.

Comment: requests has a builtin `response.json()`